# Customizing UILocalNotification's alert

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have to change the `alertView` of a `UILocalNotification`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't customize the local notification. It's only text + 1 or 2 buttons.

For further details, you can go to [Apple's local and remote notifications reference library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194).

Comment: i want to repeat only for specific days

Comment: then you have to create different notifications

Comment: @vincent, but how to delete different notification, when they are related to one alarm, like monday, tuesday..