# Show an image in the alert body of a local notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I am using Local Notifications, but I want to put an image in the message body of the alert. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also searched for the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303590/customizing-uilocalnotifications-alert). And found that we can't customize the `UILocalNotification`, so I handled this in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` by showing custom `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work. Give it a whirl:

```
UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                       message:message 
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];

    UIImage *smiley= [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley.png"];
    [imageView setImage:smiley];
    [smiley release];

    [successAlert addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [successAlert show];
    [successAlert release];
```

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila

Comment: You have not understood my question I want to customize Local Notifications Alert Message.But thanks for reply

Comment: Uh... That will add an image to the alert view. I think most users will agree that this fits your explanation. If it doesn't, you might want to revise your question :)

Comment: Oh, dang. I see now. I misread it. I just got back from school. Local Notification... Not Alert View. I skipped the first few words... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using simple images like question mark, notification, etc. I suggest [Ext JS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html) which has a Icon type alert.

You can add your images as well.

Comment: its IPhone's Local Notification