# custom view when local notification is fired

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am relatively new to Xcode, I am building a very simple alarm clock and below is a small snippet of the app. My question is: how to display a custom view ( i.e. a picture or an animation ) when the alarm is fired, and put also a " dismiss " button on it ? Thank you in advance

Nicola

```
 - (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate :(NSString *)message
 {
     UILocalNotification *notificaiton = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
     if (notificaiton == nil)
        return;
     notificaiton.fireDate = fireDate;
     notificaiton.alertBody = message;
     notificaiton.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
     notificaiton.alertAction = @"View";
     notificaiton.soundName = @"alarm-clock-1.mp3";
     notificaiton.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
     notificaiton.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday;
     NSLog(@"repeat interval is %@",notificaiton.description);

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notificaiton];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show an image in the alert body of a local notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941949/show-an-image-in-the-alert-body-of-a-local-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method

> **Handle the notificaton when the app is running**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif 
{
// show your custom alert view
}
```

> **Handle launching from a notification**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) 
{
// show your custom alert view
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but I do not understand...what if instead, I was an image, or an animation to show, can i simply put the image name between brackets and specify something like .jpg etc ?

Comment: i have write comment i.e. show your custom alert view in this section do your logic for what type animation you want to show

Comment: Thank you to both, they are good answers. My only problem so far was that I did see my custom image after clicking on the notification, but it disappeared after half a second. Thank you anyway, both gladly accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in **background** you can use Kalpesh suggested. But You cannot show a custom view directly if you have application in **foreground**. You can show an alert or customized alert and then once you accepts that alert and then show the custom view.