# How to set an image and sound for local notifications?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

In my app, I want to set an image for a `UILocalNotification`. Whenever the notification occurs, the image will be displayed, and some music will start. Then, when the user taps on the screen, the image will disappear and the sound will be stopped. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customize local notifications. You can just change the text and add one or two buttons. Please, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303590/customizing-uilocalnotifications-alert) for more insight.

Answer (score 0):

It is Not possible. You can add the launch image for notification tap.

```
 @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *alertLaunchImage;   // used as the launch image (UILaunchImageFile) when launch button is tapped
```