# How to fire Local notification with custom view instead of default pop up according to set timer in iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there any standard step by step way to use the local notification in iPhone application.

I have never worked for local notification.

I am interested to use this to create a fake call.

So, i am interested to set the timer in the local notification & as per the timer i have to set the local notification with custom view instead of the default pop up of notification.

Please suggest me the standard way to deal with local notification.

Every type of suggestions & links are appreciable in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the local notification alert. I have also once searched for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303590/customizing-uilocalnotifications-alert). Alternatively I ended with showing the custom alert when the user accepts the local notification (similar to **2Do:Task done in style** application).

Comment: is there any other way which can help me for creating me the fake call application instead using local notification....?

Comment: ultimatly i have to show the screen same as the original incoming call programmatically as per the set time...

Comment: @JigneshFadadu No.. may be with jailbroke devices

Comment: @KingofBliss... So, is there any solution for this thing, according to your point of view?

Comment: @JigneshFadadu no idea.. may be a server making phone calls.. i dont guess its possible..