# UIUserNotification for customising notification

Tags: ios, swift

I want customise my iOS app notification with image something like Viber notification? Will UIUserNotification allow this? How to do that?

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: are you talking in-app Notification with custom background image and sound when you receive remote notification from some other user to which you are not in session ?

Comment: Ok. i actually have no idea about in-app notification.But yes i want it for my app when i am using this app.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303590/customizing-uilocalnotifications-alert

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a library that make to u custom in app notifcation :

[image]

https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper

Installation

Whisper is available through CocoaPods. To install it, simply add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'Whisper'
```

Usage

The usage of the component is so simple, you just create a message in the case of Whisper, an announcement in the case of a Shout or a Murmur in the case of a Whistle, it's done like this:

For a Whisper:

```
let message = Message(title: "Enter your message here.", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor())
// Show and hide a message after delay
show(whisper: message, to: navigationController, action: .Show)
// Present a permanent message
show(whisper: message, to: navigationController, action: .Present)
// Hide a message
hide(whisperFrom: navigationController)
```

For a Shout:

```
let announcement = Announcement(title: "Your title", subtitle: "Your subtitle", image: UIImage(named: "avatar"))
show(shout: announcement, to: navigationController, completion: {
  print("The shout was silent.")
})
```